# Input width greater than the container

Tags: html, css

In the following HTML code:

```
<div>
  <label id="name-label">
    NOMBRE
    <input type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Introduce tu nombre" required>
  </label>
</div>
```

By applying the following CSS

```
div{
  border: 2px solid orange;
}

label{
  background-color: blue;
  display: block;
}

input{
  width: 100%;
}
```

The input element occupies more space than the label element that contains it.

Why does this happen? If 100% refers to the parent, which in this case is the label element... it could never take up more space, could it?

How could I solve it. Thank you very much.

Comment: You need to add box-sizing: border-box; CSS property for input tag. @David

Answer (score 1):

This happens because by default `box-sizing: content-box;` is used what means that your input is 100% width + `padding` width + `border` width.

To fix this you should remove default padding and border from the input field:

```
input{
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
}
```

or you should change `box-sizing` to `border-box` (where padding and border are included in 100% of the width):

```
input{
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

input elements are taking border and padding. You have to set it to zero.

```
input{
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Use this CSS for input field. This will fix!